# Why the Window Title in the notification system of plyer isn't working

Tags: python, python-3.x, notifications, python-module

I have implemented the following code:

```py
from plyer import notification


def createNotification(title, message):
    notification.notify(
        title=title,
        message=message,
        app_name="The_Debugged_Name",
        app_icon="pictures/main_icon.ico",
        timeout=2
    )


createNotification("Greeting Message", "Hello World")
```

The main problem with the implementation is that the notification I'm getting is with the message python along with the icon i.e. not as a title but as the small window title on the notification.

[image: Output_Message]

Answer (score 0):

In plyer you just... can't  - because [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68710577/how-to-remove-the-python-header-from-the-notification-i-am-using-plyer-notif). But you can switch to [win11toast](https://pypi.org/project/win11toast/) and do something like [this](https://github.com/GitHub30/win11toast/issues/28).